# karate: finding index of the particular element value from API response

Tags: karate

my code for finding index as below

```
* def list = nestActual #this is API response value which is given at the end
* def searchFor = { category_name: 'books3'}
* def foundAt = []
* def fun = function(x, i){ if (karate.match(x, searchFor).pass) foundAt.add(i) }
* eval karate.forEach(list, fun)
* print "==========foundAt=======" +foundAt
```

i have tried the above code for finding index where im getting foundAt index as null.

Below is my response where i want to find index of "category_name":"books3"

```
[
{
"category_id":1, "parent_cat_id":0, "category_name":"books", "slug_name":"books_1", "popular":true,

}, {
"category_id":2, "parent_cat_id":1, "category_name":"books2", "slug_name":"books_2", "popular":false,

}, {
"category_id":3, "parent_cat_id":1, "category_name":"books3", "slug_name":"books3_2", "popular":false,

}, {
"category_id":4, "parent_cat_id":3, "category_name":"mp3", "slug_name":"mp_3", "popular":false, }, {
"category_id":5, "parent_cat_id":3, "category_name":"mp4", "slug_name":"humoristiska_deckare_mysi_deck_3", "popular":false, }, {
"category_id":6, "parent_cat_id":3, "category_name":"video", "slug_name":"video3", "popular":false,

} ]
```

Please let me know how to find index of "category_name":"books3" using karate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess what, there is a far simpler way, the trick is to convert your search target into an array of primitives. Then you can use the `List.indexOf()` Java method:

```
Scenario: using the java indexOf api (will change with graal)
    * def response = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }]
    * def names = $[*].name
    * def index = names.indexOf('b')
    * match index == 1
```